# scala swing versus swt for cross platform development

Tags: scala

I'm a beginner programmer. Which one suites me better? I'm writing cross platform application. It would be nice if it will have native look. Easy html viewer api would be great.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

SWT provides a native look out of the box (it uses the underlying platform's API to create GUI elements) and AFAIK, cannot be distinguished in appearance nor behaviour from the native widgets.

However, SWT is "non-portable", so it is limited to the platforms which have native SWT implementations- however, it's got Linux, Windows, OS X, Solaris, HPUX and AIX implementations, so you'll probably will have enough with that. You will also need to be careful to package your application- SWT makes things slightly more difficult than a pure Java app, IIRC.

Swing has a native look and feel, but it is not 100% accurate.

On the subject of HTML views, both provide components to do that. Check http://www.eclipse.org/swt/faq.php#browserplatforms for details on SWT's provided browser. Swing's built-in component is pretty primitive in comparison- you might want to look into alternative libraries.